# AFContentTypeForPathExtension does not work when AFNetworking is built in CocoaPods workspace

Tags: afnetworking

I was try to build and keep the version of AFNetworking by CocoaPods, but I couldn't get the right mime-type when I using the appendPartWithFileURL method. The result of mime-type detection is always return @"application/octet-stream".
It seems like the __UTTYPE__ is not defined when building the AFNetworking project in CocoaPods workspace.

I had been tried to import the SystemConfiguration.h and MobileCoreService.h in the project-Prefix.pch in my project. Then, I can see the __UTTYPE__ is defined in my project, but the symbol in AFNetworking (CocoaPods workspace) is not defined.

For this observation, I tried to add the following code in the AFURLRequestSerialization.h, it seems work! But I'm not sure this is a good modification.

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#else
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#endif
```

Anyone has solution?

Here is my environment,

```
AFNetworking 2.0.2
CocoaPods 0.26.2
XCode 5.0
Mac OS X 10.8
```